# react-redux problem with onSubmit and async action on API call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am just taking my first steps with react and redux.
I started the project first without redux and now I have decided to implement it with redux.
The login worked before I adapted it to redux.
ThunkMiddleware is applied

Now the problem:
When I click the login button, the logger or DevTools only shows LOGIN_FAILURE. The page reloads and displays the login again.

If I change this 
`onSubmit={() => props.login(username, password)}`
to this
`onSubmit={props.login(username, password)}`

LOGIN_REQEST actions are spammed and finally (if the password is stored in the browser) LOGIN_SUCCESS. I get the actual content with correct data from the server.

What do I have to change to make the login work normally?

Thanks for your help

LoginComponent:

```
function Login(props) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    return (
        <div>
    <form onSubmit={() => props.login(username, password)}>
            <TextField
                onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br/>
            <TextField
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br/>
            <Button type="submit">
                Login
            </Button>
    </form>
</div>);
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
    }
};

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login)
```

LoginAction

```
import {
    LOGIN_FAILURE,
    LOGIN_REQUEST,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS
} from "./LoginTypes";

export const login = (username = '', password = '') => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loginRequest());
        axios.post(`server`, {
            //data
        }).then(
            (res) => {
                dispatch(loginSuccess(res));
            },
            (err) => {
                dispatch(loginFailure(err.message));
            }
        );
    }
};

export const loginRequest = () =>{
    return {
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST
    }
};

export const loginSuccess = tabs =>{
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: tabs
    }
};

export const loginFailure = error =>{
    return {
        type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
        payload: error
    }
};
```

LoginReducer:

```
const LoginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
      case LOGIN_REQUEST:
          return {
              ...state,
              loading: true
          };
      case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          let tabBars = populateArray1(action.payload);
          let navIcons = populateArray2();
          return{
              ...state,
              loading: false,
              tabBars: tabBars,
              navIcons: navIcons,
              isLoggedIn: true
          };
      case LOGIN_FAILURE:
          return{
              ...state,
              loading: false,
              error: action.payload
          };
      default: return state;
  }
};
```

component, which controls login and content:

```
function Main(props) {
    if(props.auth){
        return(
            <NotLogin />
        )
    }
    else{
        return <Login />
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the login failure error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login page is getting refresh/redirecting due to which its not handling the api request & its response properly. Please try this by updating your login component.

```
function Login(props) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const handleLogin = (event) => {
         event.preventDefault()
         props.login(username, password);
   }
    return (
        <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <TextField
                onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br/>
            <TextField
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br/>
            <Button type="submit">
                Login
            </Button>
    </form>
</div>);
}
```

After updating that, please make sure that you are getting correct value in `props.auth` through redux in your `Main` component. The Main component should have redux connection with redux auth state in your code.

Comment: Thanks. It works now.
Can you explain to me why the page immediately refreshs?

Comment: basically, you are using the native html form element which has the default behavior to redirect the page to specified action or to same page if action is missing and whole redux state flush its saved states when the page reload or redirect whether you become login or not. So thats why, we use `event.preventDefault()` to avoid the page redirection and tackle the form submission through component.